# 64 Digit Long Data Type in C++?

Tags: c++, types

When converting 63 digit binary number to decimal number in Windows 7 calculator, how is the 63 digit binary stored in the calc program?

I know the maximum equivalent value of 63 digit binary number in 64-bit machine is the maximum value of Long Long. So again, the question is, how is 63 digit number stored in the program?

Thanks,

Comment: `int64_t`, `uint64_t`?

Comment: The question can only be answered by someone that has seen the source code to the Windows 7 calculator.

Comment: So there isn't any type that can hold 64 digits?

Comment: Windows calculator uses an arbitrary precision library under the hood.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/25/141253.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calculator programs uses another data type to store large numbers. For example, they do not store as an int (1234), or float(0.1) instead, it is stored as an array [1, 2, 3, 4] or a strut defined for the number.

There are several reasons.

1. To be able to calculate very big numbers (Bigger than 64 bit, 128 bit)
2. To be able to be precious. For example, 0.9 + 0.9, in most programming languages, is not 1.8 (It is 1.7999999999 or 1.800000000001, etc). 
   So the number must be stored differently.

Yes, you can use int64_t, uint64_t, or some VC++ types, such as  _ _int64 or unsigned  _ _int64.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Ahh, that's what I thought! Stored as an array or similar idea. Thank you. I know ways around this problem but was making sure there is no sneaky data type hidden in some libraries Lol,